# Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000 error while switching between windows using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with selenium 3.13.0 and chrome version 79.0.3945.130 and java. I wrote this code for testing a web page that has to switch between 2 windows. when I start running this script everything is OK, but when the driver switches to the new window, It seems no longer available! And after a long time, I got this error.
Does anyone know where the problem is?

(I'm sure the control of the program will come out of the loop and switch to the new window but it seems to the driver will be lost after leaving the loop. )

some functions like driver.quit() or driver.getWindowHandles() worked after exiting the loop but some others like driver.getPageSource() or driver.manage().window().maximize() are not working and cause this Error.

Here's my sample code:

```
public class myClassFirst {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Driver_Path");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();      //it works correctly
    driver.get("Web_page_Url");
    Thread.sleep(15000);  //to load page
    System.out.println("finish waiting ...");
    /*
        some script here
    */
    // go to appropriate frame
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("Faci3");
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("Commander")));
    Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(s);  //print windowID of current window(1)
    //select button element
    WebElement prepareToPrint = driver.findElement(By.id("PreparePrint"));
    prepareToPrint.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);  //to load new window(2)
    String sThis = driver.getWindowHandle();   //get windowID of current window(1)
    for (String winId:driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!winId.equals(sThis)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winId);   //switch to new window(2)
            System.out.println(winId);          //print windowID of new window(2)
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("exit from the loop");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();  //From here does not work anymore(real line 92)
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.contextClick().perform();
    System.out.println("End = Finish");
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

and this is the output:

```
finish waiting ...
[CDwindow-9B003436EA7F9E41C56694893D686231]
CDwindow-7205BC1AD0022BD28BFD18FCD4FA379B
exit from the loop
[1579772104.277][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
[1579772104.280][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-BT6SU1U', ip: '192.168.67.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Sadell\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61628}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 5b36cc7b69534ede85d7c957306c2626
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:594)
    at myClassFirst.main(myClassFirst.java:92)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears

in this problem, I changed my web driver from chrome to firefox and It was temporarily resolved.
I hope this helps you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium WebDriver by default waits until the page is fully loaded. However, you can tell it not to, or to employ another PageLoadStrategy.

The following should help you.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
```

This post here helped me out when I was struggling with the very same issue using EdgeDriver. https://www.skptricks.com/2018/08/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this
driver.switchTo().window(window).manage().window().maximize()

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[1579772104.277][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
[1579772104.280][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
.
.
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Sadell\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61628}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to switch to the new **TAB**.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=79.0.3945.36* and *chrome=79.0.3945.130* and are compatible
- But your *Selenium Client* version is **3.13.0** of *2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z* which is almost **2** years older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.13.0* , *ChromeDriver v79.0* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

Comment: Mr @DebanjanB, first of all, thanks for your attention, I tried this solution but the same result was repeated. I'm sure the control of the program will come out of the loop and switch to the new window but it seems to the driver will be lost after leaving the loop.

Comment: @Sr7 That should be a different question all together with a different canonical answer. Can you update me the status of this answer please?

Comment: I updated the code of my question to show what happened better. I'm using java version "1.8.0_181". Do you think the problem is here? @DebanjanB

Comment: @Sr7 181 should be fine as I still use 171. Better upgrading to 231

Comment: Dear @DebanjanB I update my jdk to version 241 but the problem still remains.